# Swift Type property for stored property in class

Tags: class, swift

Since Type property is not supported for object stored property, having struct type property seems reasonable workaround to me.  Question: should I use inner struct or not?

I like the inner struct syntax because it seems encapsulate the interface better, but I am not sure if it would waste valuable memory space for every instance?  will it?

For example

```
class MyClass { 
  // inside the class
  struct MyStatic {
    static let MyConstant = "abc"
  }
}
```

or

```
// in the same file
struct MyStatic {
  static let MyConstant = "abc"
}

class MyClass {

}
```

Comment: Do you mean "Since **static** Type property is not supported..."?

Comment: I mean class Type Property for stored property.  Currently for class type property, only class computed property is supported at this moment.

Comment: Could you post an example of what you are actually trying to accomplish? I am not sure what you are trying to do in your examples. It looks like you have a variable of type String named MyConstant stored in a struct called MyStatic, inside or outside of a class called 'MyClass'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the closest approximation to a [Type Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_384), then you'll want to use an inner `struct`; it won't be stored in every instance of the class.  If you define the `struct` outside your `class`, then it'll become global, which is not the same thing.

`struct` defined outside `class`:

```
struct MyStatic {
    static let MyConstant = "abc"
}

class MyClass1 {
    func test() { println(MyStatic.MyConstant) } // Works because MyStatic is Global
}

class MyClass2 {
    func test() { println(MyStatic.MyConstant) } // Works because MyStatic is Global
}
```

`struct` defined inside `class`:

```
class MyClass1 {
    struct MyStatic {
        static let MyConstant = "abc"
    }
    func test() { println(MyStatic.MyConstant) }
}

class MyClass2 {
    func test() { println(MyStatic.MyConstant) } // Compile error: MyStatic is not accessible
}
```

This also allows you to re-define `MyConstant` per `class` (which is what Type Properties are for to being with):

```
class MyClass1 {
    struct MyStatic {
        static let MyConstant = "abc"
    }
    func test() { println(MyStatic.MyConstant) } // abc
}

class MyClass2 {
    struct MyStatic {
        static let MyConstant = "def"
    }
    func test() { println(MyStatic.MyConstant) } // def
}
```

You can even add a computed Type Property to simulate a stored one:

```
class MyClass1 {
    struct MyStatic {
        static let MyConstant = "abc"
    }

    class var MyConstant: String {
        get { return MyStatic.MyConstant }
    }

    func test() { println(MyClass1.MyConstant) }
}
```